# how to convert expression with | (or) in AST?

Tags: c, tree, antlr, grammar, multiplication

I have this expression in my grammar:

```
 function_expr  (('*'|'/'|'%') multiplicative_expression)*
```

I am trying to form it in AST, however with the '|' symbol I don't know how to do that. I am trying to do something like this :

```
 function_expr  (('*'|'/'|'%') multiplicative_expression)* -> ^('*' ^(FUNC_EXPR function_expr) multiplicative_expression)
```

Of course it is not correct . The best way would be something like :

```
 function_expr  (('*'^|'/'^|'%'^) multiplicative_expression)*
```

Unfortunatly I need to define some token as well.
Does someone has an idee please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
your_rule
 : (function_expr                                -> ^(FUNC_EXPR function_expr))
                 ( '*' multiplicative_expression -> ^('*' $your_rule multiplicative_expression)
                 | '/' multiplicative_expression -> ^('/' $your_rule multiplicative_expression)
                 | '%' multiplicative_expression -> ^('%' $your_rule multiplicative_expression)
                 )* 
 ;
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked :) . But I am not sure how $your_rule is supposed to work ? I suppose in this case it returns function_expr ?

Comment: @Exia0890, look at it like this: `$your_rule` consists of `function_expr` and all other rules matched by the `( ... )*`

Comment: I see thanks, and I forgot to say but there is a ")" in extra at the 3 lines : " $your_rule multiplicative_expression)) "